# InlineString vs String – qual é a diferença?

Tags: c#, .net, office-open-xml

Na criação de algumas planilhas com OpenXML, me veio a dúvida da diferença entre:

- `CellValues.InlineString`
- `CellValues.String`

Existe alguma diferença prática na hora de inserir textos (ex.: "olá mundo"; "stackoverflow")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fui achar uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6494578/221800) que fala disso:

- `CellValues.String`

É usado para armazenar o texto da fórmula usada na célula. O XML ficaria:

```
<x:c r="C6" s="1" vm="15" t="str">
   <x:f>CUBEVALUE("xlextdat9 Adventure Works",C$5,$A6)</x:f>
   <x:v>2838512.355</x:v>
</x:c>
```

- `CellValues.InlineString`

É usado para armazenar texto formatado na célula em oposição a ser o código da célula. Note que o normal seria usar a `SharedStringTable` para isso. O XML ficaria:

```
<x:c r="B2" t="inlineStr">
   <is><t>test string</t></is>
</c>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Xml.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cell?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=openxml-2.8.1).